# Set Reminder using local notification in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Here is my local notification code, I get notification daily using `[localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];`  now I want to stop or cancel the notifications after the date and time expires using end date and time. and where should I implement on those, Anyone please explain.Advance in thanks.

```
NSString *startdate = @"10-12-2016 07:00 am";
NSString *enddate = @"14-12-2016 07:00 am";
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = startdate;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",self.nameTextField.text];
            localNotification.soundName = @"bell_tree.mp3";
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

and this is my app delegate didReceiveLocalNotification codings,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(nonnull UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel that notification by using following code :

Cancel one local notification with this line of code: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification]`

You can do this in `didReceiveLocalNotification` after showing notification to user.. or pass that `"notification"` object to that class/method whether user is canceling it.

or you can implement "cancel" button click of alert, and on that click you can cancel that Reminder(localNotification).

Comment: how do I check receiving the notification date&time is equal to end date&time string. then only its possible right?, can you explain please.